# TYPO3 8.7.8 restrict available content-elements in backend-layout column

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I've been searching over and over but yet haven't found something that would work...

TYPO3 8.7.8

```
root           - backend-layout ("Main") for this and all subpages   (id=1)
|
 - home        - backend-layout ("Home") for this page only          (id=2)
|
 - subpage     - same backend-layout as root                         (id=3)
```

both backend-layouts look the same:

```
________________________________
|             Top              |
|______________________________|
| main-content | right-content |
|______________|_______________|
```

The top-section is named differently and to be used differently.

The top-section of the "Main"-backend-layout should have only allowed the images-content-element.

```
cType.allowed = image
```

The top-section of the "Home"-backend-layout should have only allowed the text-content-element

```
cType.allowed = text
```

The last two things I've tried is

first: restricting it using the GlobalVars in typoscript

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id != 2]&&[globalVar = TSFE:colPos=2]
  TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList(header,text,bullets,table,uploads,multimedia,mailform,search,login,splash,menu,shortcut,list,script,div,html,media)
  TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.keepItems := addToList(image)
[end]
```

second: changing the properties of the layout in the database

```
backend_layout {
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 2
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Parallax
                    colspan = 2
                    colPos = 2
                    # The following 3 lines have been added through me
                    cType {
                        allowed = text
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        2 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Content-Main
                    colPos = 0
                }
                2 {
                    name = Content-Right
                    colPos = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried quite a few other things and I'm not sure if I would find them again. I'm not even sure this can be done in TYPO3 8.x. The options from creating a backend-layout in typo are really restricted. You can only type a name for the column and define the colPos.

Did I do something wrong for TYPO3 8.x that my configurations didn't work?
Do I need different properties? Or is it just not intended to work this way anymore in this version of TYPO3? Because it seems that it has worked before...

I'm still quite a novice to TYPO3 and I would really appreciate your help but be specific on where to change what because otherwise I'll be lost again.... ^^

Thanks!

Comment: What about EXT:content_defender https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender/

Comment: This I could try, but isn't this possible without any extension?

Comment: @jokumer Ha!!! It worked!!! content_defender seems to work perfectly. Sad only, that I have to adapt the records in the DB. There probably is a way to do this with mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts but I don't know how and what I need to do, that I can use the backend layouts defined like this on the specific pages. For the time being only the root-page has a template... If someone could give me a pointer on how to do this (especially the second part) or even an instruction I would be unbelievably glad and relieved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Joey I found the extension to work with: [Content Defender](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender/)

And I found out how to add my backend_layouts through ts; Add the following to the PageTS of the root page

```
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
   Home {
      title = Home
      config {
        backend_layout {
          colCount = 2
          rowCount = 2
          rows {
            1 {
              columns {
                1 {
                  name = Parallax
                  colspan = 2
                  colPos = 2
                  # allowed and disallowed only work through the extension content_defender (or gridelements)
                  allowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_parallax_content
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            2 {
              columns {
                1 {
                  name = Main
                  colPos = 0
                  disallowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_bg_image,gi_customstyler_parallax_content
                  }
                }
                2 {
                  name = Right
                  colPos = 1
                  disallowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_bg_image,gi_customstyler_parallax_content
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
  Main {
      title = Main
      config {
        backend_layout {
          colCount = 2
          rowCount = 2
          rows {
            1 {
              columns {
                1 {
                  name = Titel-Hintergrund
                  colspan = 2
                  colPos = 2
                  allowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_bg_image
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            2 {
              columns {
                1 {
                  name = Main
                  colPos = 0
                  disallowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_bg_image,gi_customstyler_parallax_content
                  }
                }
                2 {
                  name = Right
                  colPos = 1
                  disallowed {
                    CType = gi_customstyler_bg_image,gi_customstyler_parallax_content
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This way the two backend_layouts are available on the page-configurations with the additional conditions of restricted content-elements. As you can see, this can also be used with custom content-elements.

It took quite a while for me to figure this out (as novice) and I hope that this might help someone else...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
    backend_layout {
      colCount = 2
      rowCount = 2
      rows {
        1 {
          columns {
            1 {
              name = Parallax
              colspan = 2
              colPos = 2
              allowed = text
            }
          }
        }
        2 {
          columns {
            1 {
              name = Content-Main
              colPos = 0
            }
            2 {
              name = Content-Right
              colPos = 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What about registering your backend layouts with `mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts` instead of DB records?

Comment: I guess the "allowed" setting will only work when the extension "gridelements" is installed.

Comment: There is the extension Content Defender too, but yes, this is not a TYPO3 core feature yet. BTW: Upcoming version of Gridelements will share the same syntax with Content Defender to allow and disallow certain values for CType, list_type and tx_gridelements_backend_layout - aka Content Elements, Plugins and Grid Elements.

Comment: @StatiX I don't actually know where to put this so that it would work. Do I have to delete the backend layouts I already have to access them later through typoscript?

Comment: @PaulBeck & Joey I've come across the gridelements but didn't realise that I would need it to use the "allowed" (was never mentioned in the issues I've found so far...). Thanks for the pointer. I'll try the solution from András Ottó. If that doesn't work I'll try using an extension.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @PaulBeck allowed actually works with content_defender as well :) I got it working with this extension. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the good way, but the condition is not correct.

Prolbem one: There is no TSFE available for the BE.

> In the "globalString" condition, key "TSFE:" will not work because the
>   TSFE global object only exists in the FE context. The "LIT:" key will
>   not work either as it is used to compare TypoScript constants, which
>   are not available in the BE context.

Reference: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/Conditions/Index.html

You need to use the "page" instead of the "TSFE:page|". These are equal, but "page" can be used for both frontend and backend but "TSFE" is only for frontend.

The second problem is, that for the colPos you need to access the GP (GetPost) helper instead of the TSFE.

So try to change the condition like this:

```
[page|uid != 2]&&[globalVar = GP:colPos==2]
  TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList(header,text,bullets,table,uploads,multimedia,mailform,search,login,splash,menu,shortcut,list,script,div,html,media)
  TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.keepItems := addToList(image)
[end]
```

Note: there is no CType restriction for the BE layouts, so both "cType" and "allowed" are wrong.

Comment: Interesting. The following condition seems to work though: [globalVar = TSFE:id = 2]&&[page|backend_layout = 2] as it gives the right output... I'll look into the documentation and I'll try your solution. Thanks :)

Comment: There is a typo in my solution, I changed it, it should be GP:colPos==2. BTW I use a similar logic with TYPO3 8.7.8 here is my condition:
[globalVar = GP:colPos==0] && [page|is_siteroot = 0]  -> So it is for the Main column and not for a Home page, because the home is the siteroot by my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As my other condition seems to work just fine I start to believe that you can either use "=" or "==" and both will work. As I've already found a way to restrict my content-elements the way I wanted I think I'll let the other conditions stay as they are. What I saw from the documentation doesn't really give any pointers which of the conditions would be the right one to use (maybe you know where to look it up?). I'll keep in in mind though if I should need more conditions ;) Thanks